# Get ID for previous/next image link

Tags: images, next-post-link, previous-post-link

For grabbing previous or next image link on attachment page we can use this

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_image_link

How do we get ID for that attachment? Because I would like to get its alt title by using this `echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);` and put it below image, with maybe also a few more stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[previous_image_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_image_link) looks like it uses [adjacent_image_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/adjacent_image_link/).

You can probably do more with the post `ID`. This example shows how to get the previous and next post, then gets any image data out of the post thumbnail.

While this doesn't directly answer your question but I'm pretty confident you can use the `ID` to get what you need. Obviously this extra function requires a `$post_id` but you can pass `get_post_ID()` if you want or use `get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post` directly.

This sample was based off of the question [Get Previous & Next posts by Post ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55259/get-previous-next-posts-by-post-id).

```
function get_next_post_id( $post_id, $is_next=true ) {
    return get_previous_post_id($post_id, ! $is_next );
}

function get_previous_post_id( $post_id, $is_prev=true ) {
    // Get a global post reference since get_adjacent_post() references it
    global $post;

    // Store the existing post object for later so we don't lose it
    $oldGlobal = $post;

    // Get the post object for the specified post and place it in the global variable
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Get the post object for the previous post
    $previous_post = $is_prev ? get_previous_post() : get_next_post();

    // Reset our global object
    $post = $oldGlobal;

    if ( '' == $previous_post ) 
        return 0;

    return $previous_post->ID;
}

$post_id = 6331;
$prev_post_id = get_previous_post_id( $post_id ); 
$next_post_id = get_next_post_id( $post_id ); 

var_dump ( array(

    '****** POST ID',
    $prev_post_id,
    $post_id,
    $next_post_id,

    '****** POST TITLE',
    get_post($prev_post_id)->post_title,
    get_post($post_id)->post_title, 
    get_post($next_post_id)->post_title,

    '****** IMAGE ID',
    $p_img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $prev_post_id ),
    $c_img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ),
    $n_img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $next_post_id ),

    '****** IMAGES',
    wp_get_attachment_image( $p_img_id ),
    wp_get_attachment_image( $c_img_id ),
    wp_get_attachment_image( $n_img_id ),

    '****** IMAGE META',
    wp_get_attachment_metadata( $p_img_id ),
    wp_get_attachment_metadata( $c_img_id ),
    wp_get_attachment_metadata( $n_img_id ),

    '****** IMAGE POST META',
    get_post_meta( $p_img_id ),
    get_post_meta( $c_img_id ),
    get_post_meta( $n_img_id ), 
));
```

**Reference**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/adjacent_image_link/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_image_link/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/

Comment: Was this helpful at all?